# Why I am getting segmentation fault when returning string from a recursive function to main in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault

I am getting segmentation fault when returning the modified string to main() from a function using C++. I have no idea what is wrong in the code. The objective is to remove the string 'rem1' from string 's1' recursively. For reference I am including my code in the post.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string recursiveRemove(string s, string rem);
int main()
{
   string s1 = "eat tdydyfygyhdy";
   string rem1 = "dy";
   //recursively remove the rem string from s
   s1 = recursiveRemove(s1, rem1);
   cout<<s1<<endl;
   return 0;
}

string recursiveRemove(string s, string rem){
    cout<<"In recursive function s is now = "<<s<<endl;
    cout<<"rem = "<<rem<<endl;
    if(s.length() == 0 ){
        //cout<<s<<endl;
        //return;
        return s;
    }
    if(s == rem){
        //cout<<""<<endl;
        //return;
        return "";
    }
    if(s.length() < rem.length()){
        //cout<<s<<endl;
        //return;
        return s;
    }

    else{
        cout<<"Entered into Else section"<<endl;
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        int startInd;
        while(i<s.length() && s[i] != rem[j]) {
            i++;
        }
        cout<<"i = "<<i<<endl;
        if(i == s.length()){//reached the end of the string
            cout<<"i = "<<i<<" s.length() = "<<s.length()<<", s="<<s<<endl;
            //cout<<s<<endl;
            //return;
            return s;//temp;
        }
        else{//match found for first character
            startInd = i;
            while(i<s.length() && j<rem.length()){
                cout<<"Inside while, s[i] = "<<s[i]<<", rem[j] = "<<rem[j]<<endl;
                if(s[i] != rem[j]){
                    //cout<<"inside if s[i]="<<s[i]<<", rem[j]="
                    //cout<<s<<endl;
                    //return;
                    return s;
                }
                i++;
                j++;
                cout<<"after increase i= "<<i<<" j="<<j<<endl;
            }
            int noOfCharsMatched = i - startInd;
            s.erase(startInd, noOfCharsMatched);
            s = recursiveRemove(s, rem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How deep does the recusion become?  Is Overflowing the Stack (a.k.a. StackOverflow)?

Comment: For testing I have used till 3 recursions. But even the first recursion gives me segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be at this line : `s = recursiveRemove(s, rem);`.

First, parameters in c++ are passed by value unless you use an ampersand (&). That means each `s` is a copy, changing it will *not* affect the original argument that was provided to the function call.

Second, your function has an execution path that does not return, and it's eventually taken. This is undefined behavior.

What you likely meant to do was return the result of your recursive function call. Try changing it to `return recursiveRemove(s, rem);`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Francois! It worked like magic. I didn't even realize the black hole there!